# C# HTMLNode get correctly innerText of div

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to correctly extract the innerText of a list of div I am getting from a website.

This is what I came up with but still a bit buggy as it misses whitespaces and the - symbol.

```
var first = mainmenuTitles[x].Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "left").Elements("a").ToList();
string final = "";
foreach (var countfirst in first)
   {
       final += countfirst.InnerText;
   }
Console.WriteLine("Tittle: " + final);
```

This is how the html code looks like

```
<div class="row row-tall mt4"> 
    <div class="clear"> 
    <div class="left"> 
    <a href="/soccer/italy/">
        <strong>Italy</strong>
    </a>
    - 
    <a href="/soccer/italy/lega-pro-group-b/">Serie C:: group B</a> 
</div> <div class="right fs11"> March 31 </div> </div> </div>
```

The text I am trying to get should look like this ->
Italy - Serie C:: group B

I am not a html guru so forgive me if it is too simple and I am missing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a query to look up all nodes with xpath `//div/a` and then concatenate the inner text to get the text you are looking for. Make sure you trim the text to get rid of extra spaces and returns.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/a").Select(x => x.InnerText.Trim())));
```

**Output:**

```
Italy - Serie C:: group B
```

Side note... you can use different queries to ensure you get the right div by using name of class as well. e.g. `.SelectNodes("//div[@class='row row-tall mt4']/a");`. This will give you all the `<a>` tags under that div.